# Relation in time for 2 points in space

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

What if I am at a point in space where 10 second of earth time is 1 seconds there, and I somehow manage to communicate from there to earth(even if it takes a lot of time, the message just arrives on earth without any disturbances(assumption))and I said "hello" for 1 second when I sent it, soo when the message arrives here on earth, will it say "hello" for 10 seconds? What is the science behind this stuff?

Comment: You seem to be asking about "time dilation".